# Why do subxt::Error not fit in anyhow::Error?

Tags: subxt

I'm implementing a client based on `subxt`, and have difficulties with subxt errors:

```
the trait `From<Result<std::option::Option<u32>, subxt::Error>>` is not implemented for `Result<std::option::Option<u32>, anyhow::Error>`
```

I see that subxt's error type derives from [thiserror](https://docs.rs/thiserror/latest/thiserror/) which should implement `std::error::Error` trait.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, thiserror::Error)]
pub enum Error {
    // [...]
```

From [anyhow](https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/) side, it should accept any type implementing the `std::error::Error` trait.

Is there some particular configuration of `#[subxt::subxt(_____)]` for error type to derive error trait?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've repro'd the error with a minimal example, and although the conversion `subxt::Error -> anyhow::Error` is implemented, it is not implemented when wrapped in a result. Thus, you can either manually use `map_err` or the `?` operator.

```rust
use anyhow;
use subxt;

fn failable_func() -> Result<Option<u32>, anyhow::Error> {
    let err = subxt::Error::Other("Here's an error".to_string());
    let res: Result<Option<u32>, subxt::Error> = Err(err);
    // The line below would fail to compile, because result -> result
    // let err2 = res.into()
    // But we can manually map the error without issues
    let err2: Result<Option<u32>, anyhow::Error> = res.map_err(|e| e.into());
    // This would also work
    let inner = res?;
    Ok(inner)
}
```